# Difference between SET NAMES and SET CHARSET

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Simply put, what is the difference between:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-character-set.html

and

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-names.html

I have looked at the connection charset page:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html

I've checked `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%'` but I can't put my finger on the difference between the two other than that `SET NAMES` has an optional `COLLATE` which sets `collation_connection`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a summary of what variables are set by each statement:

```
Variable                 SET NAMES   SET CHARSET
character_set_client     argument    argument
character_set_results    argument    argument
character_set_connection argument    default for default db
collation_connection     argument*   default for default db
```

So the biggest difference is that SET CHARSET doesn't set the connection charset to the charset you specify in the argument, instead it sets it to the charset for your current default database, that is if you have done `USE <database>`.

Why do both statements exist? I don't know, I checked the manual all the way back to MySQL 4.1 and both statements are there, but with no explanation for why they needed two statements.

I would guess it's for compatibility with other SQL implementations.